# Android Activity Group problem?

Tags: android, android-layout

Suppose There are some activity.

I want to start another activity from the main activity. and another from that activity. and another from the next one.

This is how it is -

Main Activity -> Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 3

Now I want to switch from Activity 3 to Activity 2 , when i click the back button it will show Activity 2 for few second and came back to Activity 1 suddenly . it is not stable for back button press, sometime it bring it to main actitity.

I don't know is there any way to get it done.

If someone know about this. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html refer to this will give u some solution for your problem. 
create intent and call the other activity.

```
intent i=new intent();
i.setclass(presentclassname.this,secondclass.class);
startActivity(i); will take u to other screen...
```

if u want to come back when u press on back button
just write the `onClickListener()` of that button

```
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setText("");
            finish();
        }
```

will take u to the previous screen like this u can do...